# submit button suddenly disabled when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

i am trying to insert simple username in database.
I wrote the code in bootstrap and then just copied it to netbeans and then insert php code in it.
Script is working well but when i am trying to submit to insert name in database, the submit button disabled and not giving any error or redirecting to another page.
Please help.
I am new on bootstrap.

```
<?php 

    include 'includes/db_connection.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {

   //$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   //$firstname=filter_string('firstname');
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $sql1 ="INSERT INTO student (firstname)
VALUES ('$firstname')";

$res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);  
if($res1)
{
    //$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    header("Location: successful_message.php");
    //echo 'Successful';
   // . " Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
}
else 
{

    header("Location: valid_test.php");
}

}
else{?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/ecmascript"></script>

<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/css/formValidation.min.css">
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Form</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  </head>
<body>


    <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="validate-input.php" class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>


        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
        </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
  <?php } ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Generate a simple captcha
    function randomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

    function generateCaptcha() {
        $('#captchaOperation').html([randomNumber(1, 100), '+', randomNumber(1, 200), '='].join(' '));
    }

    generateCaptcha();

    $('#contactForm')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                firstname: {
                    row: '.col-xs-4',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The first name is required'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            message: 'Name only contains Letter',
                            regexp: /^[A-Z a-z]*$/
                        }

                    }
                },
                lastName: {
                    row: '.col-xs-4',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The last name is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                phoneNumber: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The phone number is required'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            message: 'The phone number can only contain the digits, spaces, -, (, ), + and .',
                            regexp: /^[0-9\s\-()+\.]+$/
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The email address is required'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                        }
                    }
                },
                message: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The message is required'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 700,
                            message: 'The message must be less than 700 characters long'
                        }
                    }
                },
                captcha: {
                    validators: {
                        callback: {
                            message: 'Wrong answer',
                            callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                                var items = $('#captchaOperation').html().split(' '),
                                    sum   = parseInt(items[0]) + parseInt(items[2]);
                                return value == sum;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('err.form.fv', function(e) {
            // Regenerate the captcha
            generateCaptcha();
        });
});
</script>

        </div><!--End container -->
   </div><!-- End container-fluid -->




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which page is validate-input.php ??

Comment: the main page where i am writing this code

Comment: can you post code of validate-input.php

Comment: dear, the code i posted in my question is the code of validate-input.php.

Comment: this is all of my code till now.i forget to write name of file at the start of my code posted in question

Comment: Why dont you use just `input type='submit'`? Try this : `<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">`

Comment: i tried that too but that also did not work

Comment: Have checked for any errors in your console?

Answer (score 1):

1. remove action from your form

> `<form id="contactForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">`

2. you're validating to much on your script. remove other validation other than firstname
   I tried it but still need to do it twice, so after submit, change the firstname again then submit again. didn't know is it because your code of the formvalidation.js

   ```
   <?php
   //include 'includes/db_connection.php';
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $sql1 = "INSERT INTO student (firstname) VALUES ('$firstname')";

   $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
   if ($res1) {
   echo 'succ';
   //    header("Location: successful_message.php");
   } else {
   echo 'fail';
   //    header("Location: valid_test.php");
   }
   } else {
   ?>
   ```

   ```
     <script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/css/formValidation.min.css">
     <script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


     <title>Form</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <form id="contactForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Pass</label>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="First name" />
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
           <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </form>
   <?php } ?>

   <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
       // Generate a simple captcha
       function randomNumber(min, max) {
         return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
       }

       function generateCaptcha() {
         $('#captchaOperation').html([randomNumber(1, 100), '+', randomNumber(1, 200), '='].join(' '));
       }

       generateCaptcha();
       $('#contactForm')
               .formValidation({
                 framework: 'bootstrap',
                 icon: {
                   valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                   invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                   validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                 },
                 fields: {
                   firstname: {
                     validators: {
                       notEmpty: {
                         message: 'The first name is required'
                       },
                       regexp: {
                         message: 'Name only contains Letter',
                         regexp: /^[A-Z a-z]*$/
                       }
                     }
                   },
                   password: {
                     validators: {
                       notEmpty: {
                         message: 'The password is required'
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 }
               });
       ;
     });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: hey !
Value is submitting but why the validation is not working ?
I want to submit it with the bootstrap design and validation

Comment: Thanx buddy.
Actually the problem is in this line 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
..

Answer (score 0):

Above you are checking

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
```

instead of `action="validate-input.php"` write `action=""`

> Leave action empty so that the form will be submitted to the
>   document's address, i.e. the same page.

Comment: @Yo Yo
still not sending value in db

Comment: @RayonDabre
What you suggest to do ?

Comment: @zeeshanhaider : check your console if there is any error